# Automate json query to get data

Tags: python, json, pandas

Lisbon city has open data, regarding several parameters, of sensors around the city.
The JSON query is the following

`http://opendata-cml.qart.pt/measurements/RULAEQ0001?startDate=202104010000&endDate=202108310000`

This will return the registered noise levels `RULAEQ`for station `0001`between the those dates expressed in `YYYYMMDDHHMM`

There are 80 monitoring stations across the city and I would like to get the data for each one of them. The stations are numbered from 0001 to 0080.

What is the best way to automate this process in python?

Thank you in advance.

Note 1: I have the code working for one single query

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Import libraries

import pandas as pd 
import urllib.request, json 
from flatten_json import flatten

# Query URL
url = 'http://opendata-cml.qart.pt/measurements/RULAEQ0001?startDate=202104010000&endDate=202108310000'

# Read JSON from URL and decode
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

# Flatten JSON data

data_flattened = [flatten(d) for d in data]

# Create dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame(data_flattened)

# Print Dataframe

print(df)
```

Note 2 : As usual,  this is for a non-profit project and no commercial exploitation will be done.

Comment: If you can't get all the data at once: `for in in range(80):` - what exactly is your question?

Comment: for id in range(1,81):
    print(f'{id:04d}')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Import libraries

import pandas as pd 
import urllib.request, json 
from flatten_json import flatten

for station in list(range(1, 80)):

    # Query URL
    url = f'http://opendata-cml.qart.pt/measurements/RULAEQ{str(station).zfill(4)}?startDate=202104010000&endDate=202108310000'
    print(station)
    # Read JSON from URL and decode
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    # Flatten JSON data

    data_flattened = [flatten(d) for d in data]

    # Create dataframe

    df = pd.DataFrame(data_flattened)

    # Print Dataframe

    print(df)
```

`for station in list(range(1, 80)):` will loop between 1 and 80

`url = f'http://opendata-cml.qart.pt/measurements/RULAEQ{str(station).zfill(4)}?startDate=202104010000&endDate=202108310000'` will use that id and pad the string with 0s to make it 4 digits long.

Comment: `will loop between 1 and 80` it loops between 1 and 79 not 80.